# Loading Class Using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I wanted to know is it possible to load class using maven.And when i try to load class through java loadclass()function it loads the class but is not able to recognize the various imports that class has done which is fine.But is there a better way to load the class than through java loadclass() function.
Thanks

1.
Suppose there are two classes-Class A and B.I wanted A to access B and get some of the method names in class B.But i dont want to add to the classpath the dependencies.I want it to happen through maven.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please consider re-stating. Also, you need to tag this "java" as it is really a Java question, not strictly a Maven question.

Comment: Suppose there are two classes-Class A and B.I wanted A to access B and get some of the method names in class B.But i dont want to add to the classpath the dependencies.I want it to happen through maven.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Maven adds classpath dependencies when you add `<dependency>` entries to `pom.xml`. There is no magic auto-resolution of dependencies by Maven just by reading the imports in your class file.